# Possible to get symbol imagery from FeatureLayer using esri-leaflet and/or esri-leaflet-renderers?

Tags: arcgis-online, esri-leaflet, hosted-feature-layer

Have been using Leaflet with esri-leaflet plug-in for a while to add dynamicMapLayers to maps in our app.  We have implemented a tool that allows a user to click on an overlay to get attributes of the overlay using the "identify" ArcGIS endpoint.  We are also calling the "legend" endpoint to get the related imagery for each layer that returns attributes and displaying them as shown in the attached picture.  We are in the process of including the ability to display FeatureLayers from ArcGIS Online which is also included in esri-leaflet and then styled by including esri-leaflet-renderers.  ArcGIS Online does not have a "legend" endpoint nor anything similar.  The plug-ins are doing a lot of the heavy lifting by making the call to the ArcGIS server and using the renderers plug-in to display it on the map.  We have on load events hooked to each layer and looking through what is returned there, I can't find anything related to symbol information.  If I take the URL that esri-leaflet generates and put it in a browser, I can see symbol data in the returned JSON.  I know I could let esri-leaflet handle displaying the map data and make a second call directly to the server and parse the JSON, but I'd rather not make duplicate calls for everything.  Is there an easier way to get a generated image using esri-leaflet, esri-leaflet-renderers or a combination of both?

[image]